# Why isn't CURL JS loading my CSS file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, curljs

Good day, I'm experimenting with [**CurlJS**](https://github.com/cujojs/curl/wiki) and have been successful with most items.  However, for some reason I still cannot load a CSS file using [**CurlJS**](https://github.com/cujojs/curl/wiki).

Firebug (net tab) shows their `css.js` plugin as being loaded: which I assume is used to load CSS files. 
Firebug (console tab) shows 'a.load is not a function' coming from within the `curl.js` file.

**Version Number** for `define.amd.curl` is: **"0.6.2"**

**My question is:** Why isn't the CSS file getting loaded?

**MY CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        curl =
        {
            baseUrl: '.',
            paths:
                {
                    curl: 'Scripts/Curl'
                    //,'css!':'Style' //<-- I even tried this with no success
                },
            pluginPath: 'Scripts/Curl/curl/plugin'
        };
    </script>

    <script src="Scripts/Curl/curl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        curl(['css!Style/Test.css'])
            .then(
            function (css) {
                if (css)
                    alert("It Works!");
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("It failed!");
            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="test" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; width: 400px;">
            If the CSS loads this text will be RED.
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONSOLE TAB:**
[image: This is the screenshot from Firebugs Console]

**NET TAB:**
[image: This is the screenshot from Firebugs Net]

**UPDATED:**
I 'could' use the following JavaScript to load-in CSS-dependencies for a given module, but I would rather use Curls native capability.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var files = ['/Style/Test.css']; //<-- my list of files
for (var i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = files[i];
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Hey @prisoner-zero! Can you verify the contents of the css.js file being loaded?  That error says that the resulting javascript module doesn't have a "load" method.  That's strange.  FWIW, if you're using a compiled/compressed version of curl.js, you could use one that already has the css plugin baked in.

Comment: @unscriptable I have dragged it in (see above)...but am now getting 'Multiple anonymous defines in ./Scripts/Curl/curl/plugin/text.js'. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Don't pull in modules using script elements.  That will only cause problems.

Comment: Can you verify that the css.js file being loaded is the correct file?

Comment: @unscriptable Thanks for replying! My original attempt didn't include the files directly, I only tried including them after your initial comment.  They have since been taken-out.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues with your code snippet:

1. The signature of the success callback has two parameters ($, css), but you're only requiring one module "Test.css".
2. Don't attempt to load modules via script elements.  That can't work.

I can't explain the "a.load is not a function" message given the code snippet shown.  Something else must be going on that I can't see.

**[update After you posted the screen shot:]**
The tiny bit of code that's showing in that Firebug screen shot looks like the css.js file has been minimized/compressed. It wasn't meant to be minimized individually.  Use curl's make utility to build a version of curl with the css! plugin baked in, or grab a version in curl/dist that already bakes-in the css! plugin module. That should fix the problem.

Comment: #1. Sorry, this formatting was n unitentional carry-over from another attempt. However, even without, it still throws 'a.load is not a function'.

#2. My original attempt didn't include the files directly, I only tried including them after your initial comment. They have since been taken-out.

Comment: Concerning verifying "css.js"  it is loaded from the following path: Scripts/Curl/curl/plugin/css.js

Comment: Question: I chose 'download' from your Git instead of forking it...is the code "out-of-synch"?

Comment: It's the contents of Scripts/Curl/curl/plugin/css.js, not the path that I'm most interested in. :) Does it look exactly like this: https://github.com/cujojs/curl/blob/master/src/curl/plugin/css.js  (Just FYI: unless your code has to wait for the css to finish loading, you could probably use the lighter link! plugin instead.)

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post the most recent code, any error messages in the console, and any 40x errors you may see in the network section of your debugger?

Comment: Hahahaha...I'm confused too!  Anyway, it's been updated...thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CurlJS but it could be to do with the relative path to the CSS file.

Try replacing:

```
curl(['css!Style/Test.css'])
```

with either:

```
curl(['css!./Style/Test.css'])
```

or:

```
curl(['css!../../Style/Test.css'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  Thanks again though!

Answer (score 0):

Use another curl.js file ... kitchen-sink version includes the plugins, the other versions not.

https://github.com/cujojs/curl/tree/master/dist/curl-kitchen-sink